# Performance analysis of roaming authentication protocol using pbc library

Tags: authentication, protocol-analysis

Recently, I have surveyed a few research papers related to roaming authentication protocol for wireless networks. For example: [“Efficient Privacy-Preserving Authentication in Wireless Mobile Networks”](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=6636293) by Hyo Jin Jo, Jung Ha Paik, and Dong Hoon Lee and [“Secure and Efficient Handover authentication Based on Bilinear Pairing Functions”](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=6087383) by He et. al.

They used type 1 pairing having MNT curve with embedding degree 6 for implementation of their protocols. They used PBC library for implementation. I have a three doubts regarding this:

1. Is their schemes will provide the same security and efficiency as provided by the type 3 pairing using the same security parameters?
2. Can we convert type 1 to type 3?
3. Can we compare two protocols where one of them uses type 1 pairing and other uses type 3 pairing?

Comment: Keep in mind [recent work](http://ellipticnews.wordpress.com/2014/02/01/new-discrete-logarithm-records-and-the-death-of-type-1-pairings/). To quote "One interesting consequence of these works is that “Type 1″ pairings are now essentially dead."